# Postgres: Derive ontology based on lexemes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Is there a way to derive occurence statistics from tsvector columns in Postgres?

For example, lets take the following three tsvectors:

```
['sun', 'walk', 'public']
['sun', 'happy', 'warm', 'public']
['happy', 'sun']
```

I would like to find every two lexeme combinations including their occurence count which occur at least two times together so that a query results in

```
('sun', 'public', 2)
('sun', 'happy', 2)
```

Is there also a way to consider the distance between the lexemes so that ('sun' 'happy') combination would score even higher?

Every help is appreciated

Andy

Comment: What you want is called n-gram (in this case digrams) or skip-grams. As such, I think it is not (yet) available in postgres.

Comment: BTW: in most cases `n-grams` refers to character n-grams, in your case it will be word- or token- n-grams.